# visualize differences in two strings in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey i have 2 different strings that have to be compared to eachother:

```
toy_seq1 = ["AAAC"]

toy_seq2 = ["ACAA"]
```

i created 2 labels in tkinter that put them on top of eachother, i can find the difference between the 2 strings with this:

```
toy_dif = [1 if c1 == c2 else 0 for c1,c2 in zip(toy_seq1[0],toy_seq2[0])]

[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

so now i would like to change the background, or add a small line with different colors to make it easier to spot how these 2 strings differ. Does anyone know if it is possible to change the label background into multiple different sections?

Comment: Probably not with a label. Try a canvas and add each letter individually as a text object, you can then use different colors for those, or add lines as you like.

Comment: I think you will find these links worth reading ([1](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/diff/myers.pdf), [2](https://blog.robertelder.org/diff-algorithm/), [3](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/)).

Answer (score 0):

A `Label` is probably not the right choice. Instead, try a [`Canvas`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm). This way, you can draw the digits individually, know exactly where they are, and draw arbitrary lines or other decoration and use colors.

```
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
for i, c in enumerate(toy_seq1[0]):
    canvas.create_text(50+50*i, 50, text=c)
for i, c in enumerate(toy_seq2[0]):
    canvas.create_text(50+50*i, 150, text=c)
for i, d in enumerate(toy_dif):
    c = "#00ff00" if d else "#ff0000"
    canvas.create_line(50+50*i, 50, 50+50*i, 150, fill=c)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the background color of your label, just like this:

```
your_label = tkinter.Label(root, text='your text')
your_label.pack()
your_label.configure(background='yellow')
```

However note that this will change the whole label background, so you won't be able to spot immediately which letters are different.

To avoid this you can create a label for each letter:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
toy_seq1 = ["AAAC"]
toy_seq2 = ["ACAA"]
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
toy_dif = [1 if c1 == c2 else 0 for c1,c2 in zip(toy_seq1[0],toy_seq2[0])]

labels1 = []
for i, elem in enumerate(toy_seq1[0]):
    lab = tk.Label(canvas, text=elem)
    labels1.append(lab)
    lab.grid(row=0, column=i)

labels2 = []
for i, elem in enumerate(toy_seq2[0]):
    lab = tk.Label(canvas, text=elem)
    labels2.append(lab)
    lab.grid(row=1, column=i)

for i, elem in enumerate(toy_dif):
    if elem:
        labels1[i].configure(background='green')
        labels2[i].configure(background='green')
    else:
        labels1[i].configure(background='red')
        labels2[i].configure(background='red')
```

[image]